# DIV with hyperlink in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm doing some enhancement on a website. I found out that after clicking on the DIV, nothing happens. I've tried several solutions mentioned on websites such as to add `position:relative` or `z-index:1` but none of them work. Hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

How to make this DIV with link click able?

HTML

```
<div runat="server" style="position:relative;z-index: 1" id="divFUpviatt">
</div>
```

asp.net/.cs

```
divFUpviatt.InnerHtml = "<a href=""" & IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("PVI_ATT")), "N/A", dt.Rows(0)("PVI_ATT").ToString) & """>Picture</a>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put you div inside `<a>` tag rather than putting another tag inside `div`. It will work.

```
<a runat="server" id="divFUpviatt">
  <div  style="position:relative;z-index: 1" >
  </div>
</a>
```

and then put href of anchor.

```
 divFUpviatt.href =  IIf(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("PVI_ATT")), "N/A", dt.Rows(0)("PVI_ATT").ToString) & """
```

**not sure about the attribute `href`**
**Note** the `display` css property of anchor should be `block`.

As anchor `<a>` can't hold block element and `div` is a block element.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<a href></a>` tags around the outside of the div rather than inside.

Right now just "Picture" would be clickable